# Opening a new URL from the current working browser in java

Tags: java

Currently I have a website with url, for eg. say: http://mydomain/index.jsp and I have opened the site in firefox browser & consider my default browser is Google chrome.

Now in java, I need to open a new url with the current working browser (firefox in which my website is opened). When I tried to use:

```
Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
URI uri = new java.net.URI(my_new-uRL);
desktop.browse(uri);
```

The new url was opened in chrome (since its my default browser). I dont need so. Since I have all my sessions valid in firefox, I need my code to open the new url with the same firefox browser. How can I do so?

Thanks.

Comment: from where you are trying to execute this code ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems the only way is to run a command which starts Firefox with URL as an argument. The easiest way to run command is using one of Runtime.exec() methods:

```
String[] args = new String[] { "full/path/to/firefox.exe or linux binary", "your-new-url" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( args );
```

(Please see API docs for more information about exec() overloaded variants. And also check format of cmd arguments for firefox, I don't know it for sure)

An obvious disadvantage of the approach is using hard-coded path to Firefox. Probably, it's not an issue in your case.

**UPDATE**

OK. In other words, first of all it requires loading a list of currently running applications somehow. Frankly, I don't think it's easily possible in Java. And it depends on OS. As a first idea, in Linux, you can run something like 'top' or 'ps' and analyse an output to see running apps. In Windows it'll most likely require an invocation of native code (C/C++) which uses Win API for the task (btw, it might be restricted due to security reasons).

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply. I dont need this only for firefox.  I need a way(code) in java, which finds the browser used currently by a user and make the same browser automatically to open the new url (it may be firfox, IE or chrome or anything..). Thanks again. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the URL for an application which facilitates the requested feature. Hope this helps.

http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/docs.shtml#defbrowserfromsysprop

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply. I dont need such browser select option. I need a way(code) in java, which finds the browser used currently by a user and make that browser automatically to open the new url. Thanks again. Is there any way for that?

Comment: Let me check out a few options. I will let you know in case I am come across some thing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a quite old topic, but came across this requirement in my work, and I thought I would share the solution.

First you will need to determine the OS and the browser that the user is using.
For the OS you can use:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name"); 
String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
```

For finding the browser there is a pretty good explanation here:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-browser-type-from-an-applet.html

What I did, was to add in my java code this:

```
String browser = (String)win.eval("getUserAgent();")
```

and in the html which deploys the applet:

```
<head>
    <script>
     function getUserAgent() {
     return navigator.userAgent;
    }
   </script>
```

to the head part, and

```
<applet ... MAYSCRIPT height=100
```

in the applet tag, before height.
(I also added the plugin.jar to the classpath)

Now you will only have to use some if's to determine OS and browser and to handle it.
For example for linux and firefox:

```
String[] args = new String[] { "firefox", "http://www.google.com" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( args );
```

for windows and firefox:

```
String[] args = new String[] { "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.com" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( args );
```

and you will have to do it for IE  (in chrome java applets are not supported anymore)
also and handle exceptions for paths in windows...